# Deserialize Date object with Jackson in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

My data object returns data as `1604571544010`, and I need something more readable.

I tried so many things and nothing seems work, I suspect that there is a problem with `Jackson` or the spring version.

I tried to set the data format in the *application.properties*

Also I ttried all global configurations from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates)

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<jackson.version>2.11.3</jackson.version>
<jackson.databind.version>2.11.3</jackson.databind.version>
<jackson.mapper.version>1.9.13</jackson.mapper.version>
<spring.boot.version>2.1.17.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>5.1.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

**WebConfig**

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder()
{
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().indentOutput(true).dateFormat(sdf);
}
```

DTO

```java
@JsonProperty
public Date getStartDateTime()
{
    return startDateTime;
}
```

Comment: To some point, return as EpochMilli is actually useful when consumed by Javascript. As you can create JS date object directly by just `new Date(EpochMilli)`. This is normally I recommend to use to prevent the confusion about timezone.

Comment: starting spring boot 2, dates are formatted according to ISO 8601.
You normally dont have to specify all versions of dependencies, only the spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: @Chayne P. S. I know what you mean but my data model is huge and one by one  updating the properties its the last thing I would do

Comment: @ggr we don't load all spring-boot-starter-parent, only what we need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only global setting that worked for me is ObjectMapper

```
   @Bean
        @Primary
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
        {
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
            mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            return mapper;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property `spring.jackson.date-format` in application.properties to provide specifc date format for `java.util.Date`.

for eg. `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Source : [Spring-Boot application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

Comment: Ah my bad... Did you try enabling spring debug logs to check why the config you tried didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonComponent`. Any `Date` type will be serialized with this custom serializer.

```
@JsonComponent
class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

    public DateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DateSerializer(Class<Date> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
        Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {


        jgen.writeString(sdf.format(value));

    }
}
```

**Without using `@JsonComponent`**

Register the custom serializer in `WebConfiguration`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule();
        m.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modules(m);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }
}
```

or if do want to mark each field

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
public Date getStartDateTime()
    {
        return startDateTime;
    }
```

Comment: I am sure this will work, but I need a global solution where I don't have to go over each date property

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein I just add a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

Global solution:

```
    @Slf4j
    @JsonComponent
    public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"))
                .toFormatter();

        public CustomDateDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String date = jsonparser.getText();
            //if(date == null || date.isBlank()) return null;
            if (NumberUtils.isParsable(date)) {
                try {
                    return new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.trace("Long Unparseable date: \"" + date + "\"");
                    throw new RuntimeException("LongUnparseable date: \"" + date + "\"");
                }
            }
            try {
            LocalDateTime dateToConvert = LocalDateTime.parse(jsonparser.getText(), dateFormatter);
            return java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(dateToConvert);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error parsing date: \"" + date + "\" : ", e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Unparseable date: \"" + date + "\"");
            }
            
        }

    }
```

`

It is the same solution posted by Chayne but using DateTimeFormatter instead of SimpleDateFormat, because DateTimeFormatter is thread safe .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for configuring global serialization and deserialization here:  [Spring Cloud](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-09/springboot-date-format/#gsc.tab=0)

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        
        return builder -> {
            
            // formatter
            DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            
            // deserializers
            builder.deserializers(new LocalDateDeserializer(dateFormatter));
            builder.deserializers(new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(dateTimeFormatter));
            
            // serializers
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(dateFormatter));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));
        };
    }
}
```